# How to get total transactions in 30 days with datetime

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

i want to get total transactions in 30days, can someone tell me the query?
I'm using CodeIgniter Framework. and here is my database table[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/04bIz.png)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! As it stands, your question is not likely to get answered. I recommend you edit your question to make it easier to understand (and easier to answer). First, remove your screen capture. Instead, give us some sample data from your table. Second, give an example of what you wan to obtain with your query using the sample data of your table. This will help us understand the "expected behavior" of the query you are trying to write.

Comment: you should describe more.

Comment: 30 days from the current date or a specific date range?

Answer (score 0):

you need to create a transaction date column and filter it between 2 dates

```
SELECT * FROM table where transaction_date between '2019-01-01' AND '2019-01-30'
```

Comment: how to get the value '2019-01-30' ?

Answer (score 0):

you can use LIKE syntax

example

```
SELECT * FROM transaction_table WHERE timeIn LIKE '2019-01-%'
```

2019 is year

01 is month

you should get data only in January 2019